# passing value from a boolean method to another method in the same class

Tags: java

I am inside a Data Definition Class :

I have the following things defined in the class :

```
    private double areaOfPainting;
    private boolean GMUCheck;


        public double getArea(){
         return areaOfPainting;
    }

public void setArea(double a){
       if(a > 0 && a <= 36){
           this.areaOfPainting = a;
       }
}
```

// x is the value that I am getting from the user after executing the main class in Implementation class

// The following method is getting it's integer value from the user dialog of JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION. So when a user clicks on YES button, I get 0 value and 1 for NO

```
    public boolean isGMU(int x){

    if(x == 0){
          return true;
          }
    else{

          return false;
    }


}


//Now, I wanted to define a method called cost such that if the above method’s `isGMU` result is true then my cost will be `(16+areaOfPainting)`
otherwise it will be `(26+areaOfPainting)` and this is how I approached
to solve the problem :




    public int costCalculation(){

       if(isGMU()){
     return  (16+ areaOfPainting); 
     }
     else{
     return  (26 + areaOfPainting);
     }


}
```

However, I will have to supply a value to `isGMU()` method in order  for it to work. I am kind of stuck in thinking how would I pass the value
to the `isGMU` method? For `isGMU()` method, I am getting the value from 
the user, and for `costCalculation()` method, I will have to get the value
somehow from the same class, i.e. data definition class.

Please let me know if my logic is correct or not or suggest how to better 
approach this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think (in `costCalculation`) you wanted to pass an `int` to the `isGMU` method.

```
if (isGMU(areaOfPainting)) {
    return  (16 + areaOfPainting); 
} else {
    return  (26 + areaOfPainting);
}
```

Also, your current `isGMU` could be written like

```
public boolean isGMU(int x) {
    return (x == 0);
}
```

Or maybe you wanted to assign the result to the field. something like

```
public boolean isGMU(int x) {
    return this.GMUCheck = (x == 0);
}
```

and

```
if (this.GMUCheck) {
    return  (16 + areaOfPainting); 
} else {
    return  (26 + areaOfPainting);
}
```

or using a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) like

```
return (this.GMUCheck ? 16 : 26) + areaOfPainting;
```

Comment: I wanted to pass in `costCalculation` method the value returned by the `isGMU` method. If it's true, then  I would do `return  (16 + areaOfPainting); ` otherwise `return  (26 + areaOfPainting);`

Comment: Frisch Your `isGMU` is returning an integer value but the method is boolean, so shouldn't it be returning `true` or `false` ?

Comment: @Dan No, my implementation returns a `boolean`. `return this.GMUCheck = (x == 0);` assigns the boolean from `x==0` to `GMUCheck` and also evaluates for the return.

Comment: You are returning the value of `x` which is number `0` in your `isGMU` method which is an integer. Could you explain how it is boolean? Please correct me if I misunderstood something. Thanks

Comment: @Dan `x==0` is a boolean. It's `true` if (and only if) `x` is `0`. Otherwise it is `false`.

Comment: Frisch Thanks for clarifying. So, if we are passing `areaOfPainting` to `isGMU` method which will be different than `0` or `1`, then how would the `isGMU` method return `true` or `false` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution for you is to add a setter and getter for GMUCheck.

Something like

```
public void setGMUCheck(int x){
    if(x == 0) this.GMUCheck = true;
    else this.GMUCheck = false;
}

public boolean getGMUCheck(){
    return this.GMUCheck;
}
```

Now you can write your costCalculation() function like the following:

```
public int costCalculation(){
     if(getGMUCheck()) return  (16+ areaOfPainting); 
     else return  (26 + areaOfPainting);
}
```

So now what will happen when your user presses the YES or NO option from the JOptionPane, you will invoke `setGMUCheck(x)` method with x being set to the value like you described.

This would mean your isGMU function is no longer required and you can delete it :) (Or comment it out because that's better practice)